# Using a LEFT OUTER JOIN WHERE then updating same data

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have two databases running on MSSQL 2005, SOURCE and DESTINATION, which have the same structure and tables in them.

I'm trying to update data from s to d.

In this example, I'm trying to copy data from s to d using a join and only bringing across entries which aren't already in d.

I'm then trying to update the same records just inserted with vales thus:

```
INSERT DESTINATION.ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR ([ITEM_CODE],[VEND_CODE],[PRIMARY_VENDOR],[PURCHASE_MEASURE],[STD_COST],[LAST_COST],[EOQ],[VENDOR_PART_NO],[LEAD_TIME],[COST])
SELECT s.[ITEM_CODE],s.[VEND_CODE],s.[PRIMARY_VENDOR],s.[PURCHASE_MEASURE],s.[STD_COST],s.[LAST_COST],s.[EOQ],s.[VENDOR_PART_NO],s.[LEAD_TIME], s.[COST] FROM SOURCE.dbo.ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DESTINATION.dbo.ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR d ON (d.ITEM_CODE = s.ITEM_CODE)
WHERE d.ITEM_CODE IS NULL 
UPDATE DESTINATION.dbo.ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR
SET VEND_CODE='100004', PRIMARY_VENDOR='T',STD_COST='0',LAST_COST='0',COST='0'
WHERE
```

My issue is once I reach the second WHERE I don't know how to refer to the data I've just updated.  This script is going to run either every day at a set time and I don't want to overwrite that whole column with those values, just the entries that have been inserted on this execution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the [output clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177564(v=sql.90).aspx) This will let you stash away the inserted values.

```
-- item_code needs to have the same type as the source table
declare @inserted table (item_code int not null primary key);

insert destination.item_replenish_vendor (
    [item_code], [vend_code], [primary_vendor],
    [purchase_measure], [std_cost], [last_cost],
    [eoq], [vendor_part_no], [lead_time],[cost]
) -- save inserted values
output 
    inserted.item_code into @inserted
select
    s.[item_code], s.[vend_code], s.[primary_vendor],
    s.[purchase_measure], s.[std_cost], s.[last_cost],
    s.[eoq], s.[vendor_part_no], s.[lead_time], s.[cost] 
from
    source.dbo.item_replenish_vendor s 
        left outer join
    destination.dbo.item_replenish_vendor d
        on d.item_code = s.item_code
where
    d.item_code is null;

update
    d
set
    vend_code = '100004',
    primary_vendor = 'T',
    std_cost = '0',
    last_cost = '0,
    cost = '0'
from
    destination.dbo.item_replenish_vendor d
        inner join
    @inserted i
        on d.item_code = i.item_code;
```

In this case, you could just put constant values in the insert statement, instead of doing things in two steps...

Comment: Great, so my only question with that is so I have to remove / purge the temp table you set up '@inserted' once done with the script?  As I said I'm looking to run this script periodically to keep these tables concurrent. Thanks!

Comment: `@inserted` will automatically be dropped once it goes out of scope.  (at least it will now I've declared it as a table variable instead of using create table)

Comment: So on first run it returned this, which I assume is telling me there was a particular entry it didn't like in the data set.

(294 row(s) affected)
Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
The conversion of the varchar value '000196153031001' overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded.
The statement has been terminated.

  I've run it again since and it now says 0 rows affected, so I assume the code has done its job.  I'm going to go check data and report back.

Comment: You need to change the definition of `item_code` in the table variable to match the definition in your tables

Comment: So if it's a string use that instead of an int.  I will see if I can find out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have:

```
UPDATE DESTINATION.dbo.ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR
SET VEND_CODE='100004', PRIMARY_VENDOR='T',STD_COST='0',LAST_COST='0',COST='0'
```

If your VEND_CODE, PRIMARY_VENDOR, STD_COST, LAST_COST, COST are always going to be a static value, you could just put them into the first query.

```
INSERT DESTINATION.ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR ([ITEM_CODE],[VEND_CODE],[PRIMARY_VENDOR],[PURCHASE_MEASURE],[STD_COST],[LAST_COST],[EOQ],[VENDOR_PART_NO],[LEAD_TIME],[COST])
SELECT s.[ITEM_CODE],'100004','T',s.[PURCHASE_MEASURE],'0','0',s.[EOQ],s.[VENDOR_PART_NO],s.[LEAD_TIME], '0' 
FROM SOURCE.dbo.ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DESTINATION.dbo.ITEM_REPLENISH_VENDOR d ON (d.ITEM_CODE = s.ITEM_CODE)
WHERE d.ITEM_CODE IS NULL
```

but if they do need to be calculated after insert, then I agree with Laurence's approach.

Comment: Contisma, I tried this approach first and was getting an error.  This seeemed like the logical way to do it, not knowing much about SQL, but when it didn't work I changed the order of operations to, transfer all the data, then update the required fields.  Those values are always going to be set to the values in this example.  Thanks for your contribution.